# Nested SQL query Verification

Tags: sql

So here it is. 
I have 3 tables:
Song(Title, Artist, Genre)
PlayList(Name, UserName, UserCity)
Composition(PlaylistName, SongTitle)

With the following references:
PlaylistName ->Name
SongTitle -> Title

The problem is: 
Find the Name and the UserName of the user that has, in his PlayList, the most songs written by REM.

And now I would like to ask if my solution is legit:

**UPDATE:**
I've found a more cleaner way by doing this:

```
Select Name, UserName
    From (Select Name, UserName, Max(cnt)
           From (Select Name, UserName, count(*) as cnt 
                 From PlayList, Composition, Song
                 Where Name = PlaylistName and SongTitle = Title 
                 and Artist = 'REM' 


                 Group by Name 
                )sub
           )su;
```

Comment: Hopefully this is a helpful comment: your select statement should be formatted like code in your question. I suggest you edit your question, highlight the Select statement, and hit the '{}' button at the top of the edit window. This will make your question easier to read and will likely get more responses.

Comment: Thank u very much. I am writing from.my phone and I was searching for that. Really appreciate that!

Comment: `Where Name =( Any Select PlaylistName` -->> `Where Name = Any ( Select PlaylistName` , for a start. (but  EXISTS(..), or even IN() is cleaner, IMHO)

Comment: @wildplasser Thnx for ur improved solution wildpasser

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`s!

```
select pl.username, count(*) as num_REM
from playlist pl join
     composition c
     on c.playlistname = p.name join
     song s
     on pl.songtitle = s.title
where s.artist = 'REM'
group by pl.username
order by count(*) desc;
```

You can use a `limit` to get a user with the most such songs.

If you want all such users, the easiest ways are `TOP WITH TIES` (in SQL Server and Sybase), `TOP` (in MS Access), window functions (in almost any database), variables (MySQL), or a complicated subquery (MySQL, SQLite).  That piece is highly database-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for u answer. While this seems correct in the case that 2 users have the same number with limit I am limited. And that means that my query is correct?

Comment: @FrogFlex . . . Your answer will either returns one row (in MySQL) or fail with a syntax error.  Hence, I don't think it is an improvement.

Comment: That's why I use the key word ANY. It makes possible the multi-return. Or at least nthis is what I was taught.

Comment: @FrogFlex . . . I don't see where your solution is choosing names with the maximum count.  Plus, there is no group by, so the syntax is really wrong (even if MySQL accepts it).

Comment: Dear Gordon I  invite u to re check the query as the group by is there. The heart of the query is the Select with count(*).